# How to create/find application jar to deploy your spring boot maven application using embedded tomcat?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-7

I want to deploy my application using the embedded tomcat in spring -boot. I figured that I have to run the  `java -jar spring-boot-app.jar` command, but I cannot find the jar file for the application anywhere.

On running `mvn clean package` I am able to generate a war file to deploy externally, how can I do the same with embedded tomcat ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove following line from pom.xml

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

or replace `war` packaging with `jar`. Make sure you have `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in maven build plugins

The jar should then be available in `target` folder

Answer (score 0):

To create an executable jar, we need to add the spring-boot-maven-plugin to our pom.xml. To do so, insert the following lines just below the dependencies section:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

For more information,refer this :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html